# Не работает кнопка бота в Telegram

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Реализовал кнопку в telegram боте, как обработать её нажатие и вывести какой либо текст?

```
markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True)
markup.row("Время", "Место")
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Принял", reply_markup=markup)
```

Вот такой код не приносит результата

```
if message.text == "Время":
    text1 = "ВВ"

elif message.text == "Место":
    text1 = "ММ"

bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=text1)
```

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Пожалуйста, скажите, как вы обрабатываете сообщения дополнив вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

используйте handler для обработки текста

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True)
    markup.row("Время", "Место")
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Принял", reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_help_text(message):
    if message.text == 'Время':
        text = '123'
    elif message.text == 'Место':
        text = '456'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text)
```